# Trigger.io: File Access - Getting total Counts of Images in my Gallery (iPhone/Android)

Tags: android, iphone, file, camera, trigger.io

Is there any way to get the total counts of Pictures in my Gallery? We need to preview the total counts in my gallery. We can't find what API method to be used for it.

For example,

My Gallery - 30 Photos

I hope someone from trigger.io can clarify this one. Thanks!!!

Comment: I've looked in the documentation for iOS, and there doesn't appear to be a way to get the number of images in the users gallery. Therefore I doubt that this library will be able to access it either. It's not in trigger.io's documentation either: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/file.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an API we currently expose in the Trigger.io platform. As [Alex said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351095/trigger-io-file-access-getting-total-counts-of-images-in-my-gallery-iphone-a#comment23494809_16351095), there's not really a drop-in OS-provided API for that information.

If it was really critical for your app, you could probably create something workable by enumerating the [Assets Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on iOS, and querying the [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) on Android (e.g. see our [multi-image picker plugin](https://github.com/trigger-corp/plugin-multi-image-select/blob/master/inspector/an-inspector/ForgeModule/src/io/trigger/forge/android/modules/multi_image_select/API.java#L75)) from a [native plugin](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_plugins/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. it would be a nice feature in the future.